# Scala: Placing type at bottom of inheritance tree

Tags: scala, inheritance, bottom-type

Scala defines a type called `Nothing` that is a sub-type of all types.  Is it possible to define our own "bottom types" that should be at the bottom of an inheritance tree that extends from a given super-type?

For example, suppose I have some type `Foo`, and I want to say `Xyzzy` should be at the bottom of `Foo`'s inheritance tree - in other words, it should inherit from anything that inherits from Foo.  If we introduce a new type `Bar`, and `Bar <: Foo`, then `Xyzzy <: Bar`.  I'm basically looking for a way to say `class Xyzzy isBottom Foo { ... }`.  Is there any way to achieve this directly, or indirectly achieve this effect?

Comment: Could be helpful: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/195793/how-is-nothing-a-subtype-of-every-other-type-in-scala

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to come close to the idea you're looking to do. This is not a general "bottom" type for all types in an inheritance chain. Instead, it's a bottom type specific to traits that use generics. You need to reuse `Nothing` in the type definition within the inheritance structure. Take a look at `List[_]` to see how they've defined `Nil`:

```
case class ::[A](value: A, next: List[A]) extends List[A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
```

Hence, `Nil` is a `List[A]` for all `A` because the type parameter of list is defined as `List[+A]`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work:

```
class Foo
abstract final class Xyzzy extends Foo
class Bar extends Foo
```

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> typeOf[Xyzzy] <:< typeOf[Foo]
res0: Boolean = true

scala> typeOf[Xyzzy] <:< typeOf[Bar]
res1: Boolean = false
```

It appears that `Nothing` is handled specially by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I mean you could do this

```
trait Foo
abstract final class Xyzzy extends Foo
implicit def XyzzyIsBottom[A <: Foo]: Xyzzy <:< A = null

// Example usage
class X extends Foo
def xyzzyToX(x: Xyzzy): X = x
```